# How to search content inside source tab of a rich text field in Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am currently using the following code to search within Tridion. It is fetching the Items (Components and Pages) based on the input.

Question: In rich text field we have Design,Source and Preview tabs. The below code is searching for content present in Design tab only. I need the Source tab content also
to be considered while performing search.

```cs
CoreServiceSession client = new CoreServiceSession();
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient csClient = client.GetClient();

var find = new SearchQueryData
{
  Description  = "Universe"
  ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Page, ItemType.Component }
);

IdentifiableObjectData[] foundItems = csClient.GetSearchResults(find);
```

Comment: What content do you want to search for which is in the source tab, but not in the design tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try with **FullTextQuery**

```cs
CoreServiceSession client = new CoreServiceSession();
SessionAwareCoreServiceClient csClient = client.GetClient();
ReadOptions readoption = new ReadOptions();

var find = new SearchQueryData
{
Description  = "Universe"
FullTextQuery= "Universe"
ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component }
);

IdentifiableObjectData[] foundItems = csClient.GetSearchResults(find);
```

As FullTextQuery can impact on your CMS performance, you may want it to restrict to particular schema components field only.

```cs
BasedOnSchemaData basedSchemaNote = new BasedOnSchemaData();
    basedSchemaNote.Schema = new LinkToSchemaData() { IdRef = "tcm:XX-xxxx-8" };
    basedSchemaNote.Field = "FieldName";
    basedSchemaNote.FieldValue = "*SeachText*";
```